# Jquery animation sequence with $.when()

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-animate

I have structure

```
$('.qwe').click(function(){

            $.when(
                $('#q1').animate({top: 100}, 1000),
                $('#q2').animate({top: 200}, 500)
            ).then(function () {
                $('#q3').fadeOut();
            });

        });
```

It works as I need, but I want take out animation in other function:

```
    function asd(){
        $('#q1').animate({top: 100}, 1000);
        $('#q2').animate({top: 200}, 500);
    }
    $('.qwe').click(function(){

        $.when(asd()).then(function () {
                $('#q3').fadeOut();
            }
        );

    });
```

Why animation performed simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

> Try this: Use callback in jquery

```
 $('.qwe').click(function(){

        $('#q1').animate({top: 100}, 1000 , function() {

              $('#q2').animate({top: 200}, 500, function() { 

                        $('#q3').fadeOut();
               });
         });


  });
```

Comment: This method is not suitable, because I need take out animation in separate function